# How can I display jQuery AutoComplete results in a <table>, rather than a <ul>

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm using jQuery UI Autocomplete 1.8.11

I'm currently using the Remote with Caching mode, so each autocomplete execution is doing a round-trip to the server. Ideally, I would return my own HTML table, rather than the JSON it deals with by default.

I've already tried to implement [this suggestion](http://public.blackpearl.minus3.nl/autocompleter/demo/table.html) as outlined by [maartenwierda](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-autocomplete-plugin-results-as-table#fullResponseContainer_14737000000442763) but I'm unable to get it to work. I don't know if it's because of incompatible versions or if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: It'll be a bit trickier to do client-side caching if you're returning content instead of data, no?

Comment: @DaveDev I wanted to do this... but then i figured that i can put whaterver i want inside `<li></li>`, so why bother with `<table>`?     @Michael_Haren you need to cache data, not content you'll be presenting as search results, so no.)

Answer (score 3):

I think this can help you,here is the js:

```
$(function() {
//overriding jquery-ui.autocomplete .js functions
$.ui.autocomplete.prototype._renderMenu = function(ul, items) {
  var self = this;
  //table definitions
  ul.append("<table><thead><tr><th>ID#</th><th>Name</th><th>Cool&nbsp;Points</th></tr></thead><tbody></tbody></table>");
  $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
    self._renderItemData(ul, ul.find("table tbody"), item );
  });
};
$.ui.autocomplete.prototype._renderItemData = function(ul,table, item) {
  return this._renderItem( table, item ).data( "ui-autocomplete-item", item );
};
$.ui.autocomplete.prototype._renderItem = function(table, item) {
  return $( "<tr class='ui-menu-item' role='presentation'></tr>" )
    .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
    .append( "<td >"+item.id+"</td>"+"<td>"+item.value+"</td>"+"<td>"+item.cp+"</td>" )
    .appendTo( table );
};
//random json values
var projects = [
    {id:1,value:"Thomas",cp:134},
    {id:65,value:"Richard",cp:1743},
    {id:235,value:"Harold",cp:7342},
    {id:78,value:"Santa Maria",cp:787},
    {id:75,value:"Gunner",cp:788},
    {id:124,value:"Shad",cp:124},
    {id:1233,value:"Aziz",cp:3544},
    {id:244,value:"Buet",cp:7847}
];
$( "#project" ).autocomplete({
    minLength: 1,
    source: projects,
    //you can write for select too
    focus: function( event, ui ) {
        //console.log(ui.item.value);
        $( "#project" ).val( ui.item.value );
        $( "#project-id" ).val( ui.item.id );
        $( "#project-description" ).html( ui.item.cp );
        return false;
    }
})
});
```

You can check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ShadGunnerAziz/nPxb8/)

this might help too [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alforno/g4stL/)

Comment: The only problem with it is, that ur going to affect all autocompletes on the page scope with this. It is easy to only apply the custom behavior to the current autocomplete, here is my slight optimization on your code: http://jsfiddle.net/sajjansarkar/bq526h67/

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you return data as json as usual and process them in client to display in table format as such:

```
$( "#targetinput" ).autocomplete({ .... }).data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
    return $( "<li></li>" )
        .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
        .append( "<table><tr><td>" + item.id+ " </td><td> " + item.label+ "</td></tr></table>" )
        .appendTo( ul );
};
```

you can be more creative than the example above :/